# Add multiple labels through code

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am coding a social networking app using Xamarin in Visual Studio, its a portable project with an Android and iOS project.

When the MainPage class is navigated to it opens a URL and reads the page and saves it as a string. I need it to split at every "
". I'm thinking I should use a for loop but I don't know what to do next. I would like each chunk to have its own layout box, I have yet to learn which layout to use and what each one is best for. In each box, it would have a label (content) and possibly an image (if the post comes with one, it would be a URL so it would open the URL and display that image)

Basically for each one I want to be able to edit the following

```
for(string chunk : data.split("<br/">){
    <Layout?>
    <label Text="*Content from the current chunk*"/>
    if(*contains image*){
    <image>*Open url and display the image*</image>
    }
    </Layout?>
}
```

This is also all inside of a scrollview so they all scroll together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing of chunk strings not shown.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow1"
             x:Class="StackOverflow1.MainPage"
             Appearing="ContentPage_Appearing">    
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainStackLayout" />
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    // ...
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private List<Chunk> chunks = new List<Chunk>();

        // ...

        private void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StackLayout childLayout;

            foreach (Chunk chunk in chunks)
            {
                childLayout = new StackLayout();

                Image image = new Image() { Source = chunk.url, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };
                Label label = new Label() { Text = chunk.text, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start };

                childLayout.Children.Add(image);
                childLayout.Children.Add(label);

                mainStackLayout.Children.Add(childLayout);
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
```